# Xcode 4.2 edited project is not opening into Xcode 4.0.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

At my work I gave my project to a colleague for some issue solving who has Xcode 4.2 installed on his machine. After making changes he sent the same project folder to me and with a surprise I was not able to open that project on my machine running Xcode 4.0.2. It gave me error of **.xcodeproj** file does not exists. When I tried to open the same project on other colleague's machine with Xcode 4.2 installed it works fine but on my machine in Xcode 4.0.2 it is not opening. I have faced this version incompatibility issue so many times. And also so many times Xcode 4.2 is creating issues while creating ipas.

What's really wrong here?

Screen:

[image]

Comment: Take a backup of the .xcodeproj file. Right click and select "show package contents", except the fiile having .pbxproj, delete the other files. Now open in 4.0.2 and see if it works. (Not sure if this will work).

Comment: Any reason you haven't upgraded to XCode 4.2 yet?

Comment: Ya.. We have kept some machines running on Xcode 4.0.2 while others upgraded to 4.2 because so many times Xcode 4.2 gives problem in creating ipa..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. After asking the question in  iPhone Chat-Room of SO I got an answer from One fellow to change deployment target. So **I changed deployment target in XCode 4.2 to 4.0 and it worked like a charm.**